# What is the "royal snug?" (with a question mark)?

Tags: ikenfell

In one of the secret chests in The Great Hall, there is an item with the name "royal snug?" (with a question mark). It's the same as the regular "royal snug", but it's gray and has worse stats.

What's the point of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly late in the game: If you talk to Fleur at the base of the Spelltower (near the "East Schoolyard" Traveller Oak), she'll upgrade the Royal Snug? to a very powerful hat called the Winterlast.

> [image: Winterlast screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, I'm so glad I did not sell it.